# Calculate missing y between two points

Tags: coordinates, points

I would like to know how to calculate the missing y coordinate between the two know points. The x position of the point is know only the y position is unknow. How do i calculate the position with the know points?

the known points are:

point 1:
x: -4000
y: 4000

point 2:
x: 4000
y: 0

point 3:
x: -1000
y: ?

I tried using a map function but it did not work.

[Visual of the missing point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXt2J.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Find out the line equation joining point 1 and point 2 using "2 point form of a line" formula.

As point 3 is lying on this line, you can substitute the x co-ordinate of point 3 in the above obtained equation and get the unknown y co-ordinate!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got some help of a coworker. We came up with the following method that calculates the crossing point of two lines.

```
/// <summary>
        /// This method calculates the crossing x and y point with two lines
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="newMessage">The new position</param>
        /// <param name="point1">The first point of the line</param>
        /// <param name="point2">The second point of the line</param>
        /// <returns>A new point with the x and y position of the crossing point if the lines do not cross a point with the values -4001, -4001 is returned</returns>
        public static Point CalculateCrossingPointOfTwoLines(LaserMessage newMessage, Point point1, Point point2)
        {
            int currentXPosition = LaserConnectionLogic.PreviousLaserMessage.X;
            int currentYPosition = LaserConnectionLogic.PreviousLaserMessage.Y;

            Point lowestPoint = point1.Y < point2.Y ? point1 : point2;

            double yDifferenceCurrentAndNew = currentYPosition - newMessage.Y;
            double xDifferenceCurrentAndNew = newMessage.X - currentXPosition;
            double c1 = yDifferenceCurrentAndNew * newMessage.X + xDifferenceCurrentAndNew * newMessage.Y;
            double a2 = point2.Y - point1.Y;
            double crossedLineLengthDifference = point1.X - point2.X;
            double c2 = a2 * lowestPoint.X + crossedLineLengthDifference * lowestPoint.Y;
            double determinant = yDifferenceCurrentAndNew * crossedLineLengthDifference - a2 * xDifferenceCurrentAndNew;
            if (determinant == 0)
            {   // lines do not cross
                return new Point(-4001, -4001);
            }

            double x = (crossedLineLengthDifference * c1 - xDifferenceCurrentAndNew * c2) / determinant;
            double y = (yDifferenceCurrentAndNew * c2 - a2 * c1) / determinant;
            return new Point(x.ToInt(), y.ToInt());
        }
```